# Error "Exception while loading the app" in Glassfish

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish

Before you burn me alive because of the low level informations, let me explain why... I really don't get where this error is coming from... So I don't know where I could be messing up
 It's basically an error wich comes from time to times and the only way I can solve is reinstalling Netbeans along with Glassfish and pray for not coming back.

I change some random class, and boom! This error appears. Not even erasing all that I've code so far can solve.

Glassfish grant me with this error(There's more in the log, but I guess its not worth putting here):

`Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file com/enterprise/dao/SomeClassDao`

The funny part is... I didn't change this class, It doesnt have any relation with the one I was working on!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you building the WAR/EAR? Using Maven or what? Is the class `com/enterprise/dao/SomeClassDao` obfuscated for the question or so? I can explain this problem for classes coming from the Java EE such as `javax.faces.*`, but not for classes coming from own project. It would indicate that the build is seriously messed up.

Answer (score 1):

If you're tired of reinstalling Netbeans, try clearing up Netbeans' cache first.